# MYSQL select random of each of the categories

Tags: mysql, random

I want to select random 5 records from each categories in the same table.

table name: t_shop

column name: shop_id, shop_categoryID

For example:
shop_id | shop_categoryID

```
1 | 1
2 | 1
5 | 1
7 | 1
9 | 1
10| 1
13| 2
15| 2
22| 2
23| 2
25| 2
```

I have tried using limit in subquery, but an error occur: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

I would like to ask are there any ways to solve? Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far (i.e. the query you are referring to).

Comment: SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT *
 FROM t_shop
 ORDER BY RAND()
) AS T
GROUP BY shop_CategoryID
ORDER BY shop_CategoryID

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM t_shop sod
    WHERE shop_categoryID IN
    (
        SELECT shop_categoryID
        FROM t_shop
        WHERE shop_id = sod.shop_id
        ORDER BY shop_categoryID limit 5
    )

Answer (score 1):

If you have two categories (as in your question), the easiest way in MySQL is to use `union all`:

```
(select * from t_shop where category = 1 order by rand() limit 5)
union all
(select * from t_shop where category = 2 order by rand() limit 5)
```

Comment: @KC . . . You can add an additional subquery for each category.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN t.* 
FROM (SELECT @r:=0, @c:= null) AS rownum_init,
   (SELECT *, (@r:=IF(@c=shop_categoryID, @r+1, 1)) AS rownum, (@c:=shop_categoryID) 
    FROM t_shop
    ORDER BY shop_categoryID, RAND()) AS t
WHERE t.rownum <= 5;
```

Here's the output in my test on MySQL 5.5.30, using your test data:

```
+---------+-----------------+--------+-----------------------+
| shop_id | shop_categoryID | rownum | (@c:=shop_categoryID) |
+---------+-----------------+--------+-----------------------+
|       5 |               1 |      3 |                     1 |
|       1 |               1 |      1 |                     1 |
|       9 |               1 |      5 |                     1 |
|       2 |               1 |      2 |                     1 |
|       7 |               1 |      4 |                     1 |
|      22 |               2 |      3 |                     2 |
|      23 |               2 |      4 |                     2 |
|      25 |               2 |      5 |                     2 |
|      13 |               2 |      1 |                     2 |
|      15 |               2 |      2 |                     2 |
+---------+-----------------+--------+-----------------------+
```

Usually the advice about any solution involving `ORDER BY ... RAND()` is that it's not scalable, and it becomes more costly as the size of your table grows.  But for complex random selection problems like the one you describe, it may nevertheless be the only way to solve the problem.  Just don't be surprised if it performs poorly.

---

Re your comment:

I don't understand what you mean.  Rownum has a distinct value starting at 1 in each category, then it starts over at 1 as the category changes.

Comment: thanks for you reply, 
I would like to ask, why there are several same values of 'rownum' occur at the same categoryID?

Comment: just like this..
http://s16.postimg.org/f6r8hzj5x/image.png#
I have more than 5 records in each category, and that's why I want to get random five records...

Comment: I'm sorry, I am testing with many rows too, and I can't reproduce that problem or think how it is happening.

Comment: i am now trying to select those record using 'group by rownum, shop_categoryID'


SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN t.*
FROM (SELECT @r:=0, @c:= null) AS rownum_init,
   (SELECT *, (@r:=IF(@c=shop_categoryID, @r+1, 1)) AS rownum, (@c:=shop_categoryID) 
    FROM t_shop
    ORDER BY shop_categoryID, RAND()) AS t
WHERE t.rownum <= 5 group by shop_categoryID, rownum 
order by shop_categoryID;